# How do I round a React component property value to 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I tried using {val}.toFixed(2) but since I have to return that value all it does is return the value and the string ".toFixed(2)". I also tried {val.toFixed(2)} but it throws an error because "val.toFixed(2)" is not a function. It's located at the Statistic Component

(I'm currently studying FullStack Open from the University of Helsinki)

How do I do this?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


const Button = ({ onClick, text }) => (
  <button onClick={onClick}>
    {text}
  </button>
)

const Statistic = ({text, val}) => {
  
  return (
  <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{text}</td>
      <td> {val}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  )
}
const Statistics = ({total, good, neutral, bad}) => {
  
return (
  <div>
<Statistic text = "good" val = {good} />
<Statistic text = "neutral" val = {neutral} />
<Statistic text = "bad" val = {bad} />
<Statistic text = "total" val = {total} />
<Statistic text = "average" val = {(good - bad) / total} />
<Statistic text = "positive" val = {good / total + "%"} />
</div>
)
}

const Feedback = ({total, good, neutral, bad}) => {
if (total === 0) {
return (
  <div> No feedback given. </div>
  )
} 
return (
  <Statistics total = {total} good = {good} bad = {bad} neutral = {neutral}/>
)
}

const App = () => {
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0)
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0)
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0)
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)
  
  const addGood = () => {
    setGood(good + 1)
    setTotal(total + 1)
  }

  const addBad = () => {
    setBad(bad + 1)
    setTotal(total + 1)
  }

  const addNeutral = () => {
    setNeutral(neutral + 1)
    setTotal(total + 1)
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <h1>Give your Feedback!</h1>
    <Button onClick={addGood} text="Good!" />
    <Button onClick={addNeutral} text="Neutral" />
    <Button onClick={addBad} text="Bad" />
<h1>Statistics</h1>
<Feedback total = {total} good = {good} bad = {bad} neutral = {neutral} />
    </div>
    
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
  )
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are getting error because `.toFixed` is a part of Number and `val = {good / total + "%"} ` will pass string

Comment: what @Rajesh said. Also you should call methods only if the value is present to prevent errors, something like this: {val && val.toFixed(2)}

Comment: @maten I wouldn't say that as a blanket statement - that depends on the component. If a component always expects a prop to be present, it's up to the parent component to take care of that.

Comment: @Rajesh I'd add that as an answer. Just do `val.toFixed(2)` in `Statistics` instead of `Statistic`.

Comment: @cbr you are right, i only checked the component in question, however i can see that the value is initialized as 0 in the parent, so my comment is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the `val` as prop in whatever format from the `Statistics` component itself. The `Statistic` component should just be a dumb component. In this way you don't need to handle the type even.

Try:

```
const Statistics = ({total, good, neutral, bad}) => {

return (
 <div>
   <Statistic text = "good" val = {good.toFixed(2)} />
   <Statistic text = "neutral" val = {neutral.toFixed(2)} />
   <Statistic text = "bad" val = {bad.toFixed(2)} />
   <Statistic text = "total" val = {total.toFixed(2)} />
   <Statistic text = "average" val = {((good - bad) / total).toFixed(2)} />
   <Statistic text = "positive" val = {(good / total).toFixed(2) + "%"} />
 </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass your value like this `val = {good / total + "%"}`, it gets converted to a string due to [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion) that's why you're not able to use toFixed on val

Either you can use `toFixed` while passing the prop

`<Statistic text = "positive" val = {(good / total).toFixed(2) + "%"} />`

Or, you can pass unit separately, and use toFixed on the 'val'

```js
const Statistic = ({text, val, unit}) => {
  return (
  <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{text}</td>
      <td> {parseFloat(val).toFixed(2)} + unit}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  )
}

//......
<Statistic text = "average" val = {(good - bad) / total} unit="" />
<Statistic text = "positive" val = {(good / total)} unit="%" />
```